# Error using mouseClicked method

Tags: java, eclipse, mouseclick-event

I'm trying to use the `mouseClicked` class in my program just to test and figure out. The only problem is that every time I use it I get an error telling me that "void" is the wrong type for `mouseClicked`. Every website and tutorial I've visited shows me that void is the type I should be using. Here's my code:

```
public static void door1(){
    int x = c.getHeight() / 10;
    int y = c.getHeight() * 20 / 100;

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
       c.drawLine("It worked!",y, x);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely incorrect Java syntax. You are trying to write a method inside a method. I think you got all the tutorials wrong as `mousClicked` is a method (not a class) of `MouseListener`, typically used as an anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest methods in Java. Your class must implement [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseClicked%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) inorder to use [`mouseClicked()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseClicked%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29).

You will also need to implement:

```java
void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) // Invoked when a mouse button has been pressed on a component.

void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) // Invoked when a mouse button has been released on a component.

void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) // Invoked when the mouse enters a component.

void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) // Invoked when the mouse exits a component.
```